# Editing a particular stylesheet from a php file

Tags: php, css

EDIT:
What I want to do is to add css code to my existing css file. I don't know if "c" mode for fopen is good and I don't know if I need anything else added or deleted, but I have read that "c" just adds code to the beginning of the file, without deleting everything from it.

```
$handle = fopen("mt_custom_services.css", "r");  
    .mt--custom_services:hover {  
    background-color: '.esc_attr($custom_service_background).' !important;  
    }  
    .mt--custom_services .hover_container .hover_container_holder .custom_service_second_title {  
    color: '.esc_attr($custom_service_title_color).';  
    }  
    .mt--custom_services .hover_container .hover_container_holder .custom_service_description {  
    color: '.esc_attr($custom_service_description_color).';   
    }  
    .mt--custom_services .hover_container .more-link {  
    color: '.esc_attr($custom_service_button_color).';    
    }  
    .mt--custom_services .hover_container {  
    background-color: rgba(35, 35, 49, 0.7);  
    }
```

Comment: does if else work for your question?

Comment: explain your question again in structured pieces, use some code instead